# Can't create a new test Apollo Server

Tags: node.js, jestjs, apollo, ts-jest, typegraphql

I would like to [test my resolvers](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/testing/testing/) with the [executeOperation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/testing/testing/#executeoperation) API, according to the docs I need to create a test server, here's mine.

```js
export const getTestServer = async () => {
  const redis = new Redis({});

  const schema = await buildSchema({
    resolvers: [UserResolver],
    validate: false,
  });

  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: ({ req, res }): AppContext => {
      req = mocks.createRequest();
      req.session.userId = 1;

      return { req, res, redis };
    },

  return server;
};
```

In here, I'm using [typegraphql](https://typegraphql.com/) for building my schema and this code works for my actual server, but in my tests it throws the following error:

```
    Some errors occurred while generating GraphQL schema:
      Type Query must define one or more fields.
    Please check the `details` property of the error to get more detailed info.

       9 |   const redis = new Redis({});
      10 |
    > 11 |   const schema = await buildSchema({
         |                  ^
      12 |     resolvers: [UserResolver],
      13 |     validate: false,
      14 |   });

      at Function.generateFromMetadata (node_modules/type-graphql/dist/schema/schema-generator.js:20:23)
      at buildSchema (node_modules/type-graphql/dist/utils/buildSchema.js:10:20)
      at getTestServer (src/__tests__/config.ts:11:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/resolvers/user.test.ts:19:20)
```

Comment: Can you paste the code of your resolver and your object? Also, the official example straight from typegraphql repo shows how to get a basic app working as well as, in this specific case, how to output the actual graphql schema that is generated based on your model and resolvers: https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/blob/master/examples/simple-usage/index.ts but in general it sounds like you forgot to use some decorator somewhere, so more code could be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I need at least 1 `@Query` decorator in my resolvers, I just added a dummy resolver until I need an actual query. For testing, I switched to [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest), check [this example](https://github.com/deLimaNicolas/graphql-typescript-jest-boilerplate) if you are interested in using it too for testing